# Add preloaded views in recycleview in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-recyclerview

I need to load multiple webpages, let's say
"http://www.twitter.com","http://www.facebook.com","http://www.gmail.com","http://www.pintrest.com", etc.

I want them to be shown with any delay for loading while user swiping next and back, To achieve this i have used a Recycler view having a webview at its each address, Now when i gives the list for each url from the list of url,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleViewAdapter.WebViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.webView.loadUrl(urlList.get(position));
}
```

This reload the links every time when i move on next back indexes of recycler view.

How can i load all webviews at the indexes of recycler view at once ? So that they didn't load at run time when the view get selected?

One way i tried is to make an arraylist of webviews, and loads the url in every webview and then pass that array to recycler view adapter and assign that view as,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleViewAdapter.WebViewHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.webView=webViewsList.get(position);
}
```

But this didn't work, any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution for this, as i am having same problem. Can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the item view cache size higher.

[recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(int cacheSize)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setItemViewCacheSize(int))

Comment: This didn't help :(

Comment: Please can you post your remaining code, so i can help more?

Answer (score -1):

Maintain boolean once page loaded, and use it in onBindViewHolder